# Simple RPC Call in Go

Tags: go, rpc

I am trying to get a minimal application working using RPC calls in Go. I am heavily borrowing from the [online example](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#pkg-overview), as you can see from my code:

server.go:

```go
package main

import (
    [...]
)

type InfoDumper int

func (s *InfoDumper) Dump(request string, reply *string) error {

    fmt.Println("Woooh imma deliverin stuff\n")

    current_time := time.Now()

    h:= sha1.New()
    var barray []byte
    copy(barray, request)
    hash_rq := h.Sum(barray)

    *reply = request + "\n" + current_time.Format(time.ANSIC) + "\n"  + string(hash_rq) + "\n"
    return nil
}


func main() {

    server := new(InfoDumper)

    rpc.Register(server)
    rpc.HandleHTTP()

    l, e := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:40000")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }

    http.Serve(l, nil)

}
```

client.go:

```go
package main

import (
    [...]
)

func main() {

    client, e := rpc.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:40000")

    if e!=nil {
        fmt.Println(e)
    }   else {
        fmt.Println("wooh server is ok")
    }

    in:= bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    for {

        line, _, _ := in.ReadLine()
        request := string(line)
        var reply string

        e = client.Call("InfoDumper.Dump", request, &reply)

        if (e!=nil) {
            fmt.Println("omg error!", e)
        }

        fmt.Println(reply)
    }

}
```

The only difference I can see is that I wrote `http.Serve(l, nil)` instead of `go http.Serve(l, nil)` ; this is because writing with `go` makes my server terminate right away.
InfoDump is supposed to reply with a copy of whatever was sent, the time and hash of the request.

This is what's happening right now:

- I run server.go in a terminal
- I run client.go in another terminal, after a second or so "wooh server is ok" is printed
- I type something and hit Enter on the client's side
- either nothing happens, or "rpc: client protocol error: unexpected EOF" is printed on the client's side
- if nothing happened, terminating the server (ie hitting Control-C) makes the client print the error above

In either case, "Woooh imma deliverin stuff" is never displayed on the server's side...

This was done during class as a preliminary step to get acquainted with RPC in Go before going on to more serious exercises ; all the other students managed to get this step working, looked at this code and couldn't see the difference with theirs.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this code?

Comment: First step: Do not ignore the errors returned from ReadLine.

Comment: @Volker: left most of the error checking out for brevity; in the case of ReadLine (and all other calls really, except for client.Call), no error is returned (==nil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I noted in my [mailing list response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/FUOlDWeCj28/DkSlVm17JGAJ), you will need to use [DialHTTP](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#DialHTTP) if you want to connect to an RPC server that you have served using [HandleHTTP](http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/#HandleHTTP).

I've made some other notes about your code (including styling: use gofmt and MixedCaps, per [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html), and be sure to bail out on errors) on the mailing list.